# How can I dynamically generate a user specific manifest file for html5 offline storage for user specific content?

Tags: html, mobile, manifest, offline-caching, cache-manifest

With this web app a user can select their online portfolio and view it in the browser. In safari mobile the user can add the portfolio to the home screen. But the issue is every time they open the portfolio web app from the home screen it has to reload and download the entire portfolio. I want it so when they open the portfolio all the content is available offline.

So this is why I want to use html offline storage using the manifest file. Everywhere I read about creating one manifest file for app but what if the manifest file needs user specific images and content from the server? I can dynamically generate a manifest file for each users portfolio but how can I get this to work?

It would also be great so be able to update the offline app by having the app check for network connection on startup and if so, compare the manifest file with the servers to check any changes...otherwise just load the offline content